# How do TLD DNS registries and registars maintain the TLD zone file?

Tags: dns

Let's say that I want to register a subdomain (test-asdf12345678.com) in a specific TLD (com). I choose a DNS registar (Ex: GoDaddy) and I go and purchase that subdomain. Assuming that the domain is not already taken and I have 2 Authoritative nameservers for this domain I should be able to lease it.

Root nameservers do not keep information about each registar which is authorized to make changes in the specific TLD. They just keep information about a couple of nameservers, which probably belong to DNS registries. In this case the registry for com is VeriSign, so I presume the nameservers listed [here](https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone) (like a.gtld-servers.net. , b.gtld-servers.net. , ...) belong to VeriSign.

This would mean that root nameservers "point" to a registry which then "points" to the nameservers of the end user. No DNS traffic goes through the DNS registars.

Do registars (GoDaddy in this case) keep any zone file for the .com zone in their networks, or do they just send the customer information (mine) to VeriSign and VeriSign makes changes in their zone file for .com ?

In other words when I do:

```
dig @1.1.1.1 myserver.test-asdf12345678.com
```

Do the DNS queries go through DNS registars (GoDaddy) at all or just go to through the DNS registries (VeriSign) and then reach my nameservers ?

**Let's assume that there is no caching involved at any level.**

Comment: [What Is DNS? | How DNS Works | Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Let's assume that there is no caching involved at any level.

> **The 8 steps in a DNS lookup**:
>
> 1. A user types ‘example.com’ into a web browser and the query travels into the Internet and is received by a DNS recursive resolver.
> 2. The resolver then queries a DNS root nameserver (.).
> 3. The root server then responds to the resolver with the address of a Top Level Domain (TLD) DNS server (such as .com or .net), which
>      stores the information for its domains. When searching for
>      example.com, our request is pointed toward the .com TLD.
> 4. The resolver then makes a request to the .com TLD.
> 5. The TLD server then responds with the IP address of the domain’s nameserver, example.com.
> 6. Lastly, the recursive resolver sends a query to the domain’s nameserver.
> 7. The IP address for example.com is then returned to the resolver from the nameserver.
> 8. The DNS resolver then responds to the web browser with the IP address of the domain requested initially.
>
> Once the 8 steps of the DNS lookup have returned the IP address for
>   example.com, the browser is able to make the request for the web page:
>
> 9. The browser makes a HTTP request to the IP address.
> 10. The server at that IP returns the webpage to be rendered in the browser (step 10).
>
> [image]

Source [What Is DNS? | How DNS Works | Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)

Comment: Yes, everyone says TLD nameserver, but no one says specifically the registry or the registar; whether there is DNS communication between them or not; whether the registry maintains the full zone file with all the subdomains from all the registars that are allowed to make changes to the TLD domain or the registars maintain their own .com zone file and the registry somehow points to them from its zone file. If TLD Server is the registry's nameserver then this would mean that registars do not need to have any nameservers running at all, except for their internal needs and such.

Comment: @Subzero123 That depends on the registrar. Some maintain their own DNS servers others don't. That part of your question is no possible to answer. Please read [DNS Servers: Authoritative vs. Recursive vs. Root vs. TLD | Keeping you connected with everything from Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/en-GB/Blog/Article?Article=DNS-Servers-Authoritative-Recursive-Root-TLD)

Comment: My question remains unanswered, but thank you for your time. I'll try to go through the logs of a resolver to see what's happening.